# Blank paths in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use resources to create routes in Ruby on Rails, but I do not want paths in the URLs. (e.g. `/fishing/3` instead of `/board/fishing/thread/3`.) Here is my current route configuration.

```
resources :board, :only => [:index, :create, :new], :path => '' do
    resources :thread, :only => [:index, :create, :new], :path => ''
end
```

However, the routes are out of order. For example, `/:board_id(.:format)` appears before `/new(.:format)`, so it is impossible to reach the thread#new action. Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 0):

So this is a little tricky as it can mess with other routes. Your current solution likely makes routes with double slashes in the url //. This route should be near or at the bottom of your routes file so all other valid routes are found first.

```
match '/:board_id/:id' => 'thread#show', :constraints => { :id => /\d*/ }
```

Comment: Surprisingly my current route configuration does not leave double slashes, and I haven't had any other problems with it besides the ordering. Your question seems to suggest that I should manually implement matches for every action and call it a day. Now that I think about it, that wouldn't be too bad at all since helper functions are generated with the :as directive.

Comment: That seems odd i would suspect that your path to new thread with your current implementation would look like "//fishing//new"